# Save updated data in a div to a database using jquery, ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a div that contains table rows and columns of a spreadsheet (I am using http://jquerysheet.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.x/jquery.sheet.html), on button click i use ajax to fetch the contents in the div by the id into the database. Problem is when i update the spread sheet and saves, it doesn't send the updated content to the database. It rather sends the default content.

### Button

```
<a href='#' id="fat-btn" class="btn btn-info" data-loading-text="Saving, Please Wait ..."> Save Sheet </a>
```

### Jquery / Ajax

```
$('#fat-btn').click(function() {

            var content = $('#sheetParent').html();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'sendtodatabase.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    content: content
                }
            });
        });




    });
```

### sendtodatabase.php

```
<?php

require_once("conn.php");

$resval=$_REQUEST['content'];

$ins=mysql_query("update tabula set sheet='$resval' where id='5'")or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

### Div

```
<div id="sheetParent">    

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Can anyone help me on how to get the updated div contents into the database?
NOTE: Im a novice.

Comment: Just a tip, because I'm assuming your `id` is an `integer` field. You do not need to escape the `5`. You can run queries with just `"update tabula set sheet='$resval' where id=5"` (You should also test your query directly on the SQL Server).

Comment: Thank you Killrawr, will have that in mind. The sql query works perfectly but its the contents in the div that doesn't get updated on the server.

Comment: So, you want to update a field in the database with the hole content of a `div`? Before going into the code, what type of fields are you using, and why would you do that?

Comment: @w0rldart..The div contains table rows and columns, which makes up a spread sheet (http://jquerysheet.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.x/jquery.sheet.html) This is the spreadsheet script i am using.since they did not give any relevant info on how to save the spreadsheet into a database, i came up with my own idea by taking the contents of the div that generate the spreadsheet and dumping it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

The div you are trying to put into database does not contain the data you want to save, it's rendered in a new element (i recommend having a look at the actual source of your sheet, you'll see there's a lot going on (jSUI, etc.). 
Have you tried this event?

```
sheetSave: function(e, jS, tables)
```

'tables' being one of the parameters should give you the data you're looking for. hth